# What's up with the Grothendieck circle?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I was just going to check something in FGA and I didn't have access to my pdf-copy, so I did what I normally do when in such a circumstance: surf to the Grothendieck circle's webpage.

And what did I find there? All mathematical texts written by Grothendieck himself was removed "per his request".

Does anyone know what this is about and/or what's going on here?

Comment: http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/grothendiecks-letter/ http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/02/grothendieck_said_stop.html

Comment: I saw Illusie recently and asked him whether this was true (you can't believe everything you read on the internet!) and he assured me that it was, and said that it was very sad.

Comment: meta.MO got the scoop on that one!  http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/205/strange-message-on-yves-laszlos-sga-4-page/#Item_27 .  

Comment: :-(           .

Comment: In fact, it's probably my fault that the Grothendieck circle found out about it =(.  I only found out about it when I was trying to download SGA 4 from Yves Laszlo's site.

Comment: grr :/ I really loved that webpage. Lucky me I've get the most "essential" things downloaded already. Does anyone know if all this affects the "tex-ifying-project" of SGA also?

Comment: I'm downvoting because I think this is a topic for blogs rather than for mathoverflow.

Comment: Daniel- I (sort of) disagree.  I don't think we should have a long discussion about it here, but I think the question and an answer saying "Yes, Grothendieck requested that, you can read about it here" is OK (obviously, since I left such an answer).  This page is the 6th Google hit for Grothendieck circle, so we might as well put something sensible here.

Comment: For future reference, I made a copy of the Grothendieck website's contents before it was taken down, and posted it to my Grothendieck site: http://wstein.org/sga/  

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grothendieck seems to have requested that all his materials be taken town.  As pointed out in comments, this has been discussed fairly [thoroughly](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2010/02/09/grothendiecks-letter/) on [the blogs](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/02/grothendieck_said_stop.html) and, in fact, [on meta](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/205/strange-message-on-yves-laszlos-sga-4-page/#Item_27).

Comment: Obviously, I should have paid more attention to what's going on in the world: I've totally missed this debacle. Thanks all for directing me to the relevant threads, blogs and discussions.